# MySQL BLOBs corrupted

Tags: mysql

Storing some kinds of file in a BLOB/TEXT field in MySQL seems to corrupt them - as far as I can work out is it because two null characters are appended to which some formats (eg. GIF) are tolerant, while others (eg, MS Office documents) are not.  Does anyone know of a solution/workaround/alternative practice to this?  Storing files in a directory instead (which all the CMS's I've seen seem to do) is not secure.  Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: As you are saying that null character are getting appended there must be some problem in code of storing the blob content. Pl post that code

Comment: `BLOB` is a binary column type but `TEXT` is not...

Comment: I would recommend you to store the document into the server and save the file name and the path in a varchar field

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that well at all.  The content is base64_encode()'d before being stored and base64_decode()'d before being passed to the browser to serve using HTTP headers - this is the point at which the extra characters are added.  It's an old problem - I'll try to recreate it and post some code. Thanks

Comment: Actually, seems to be working now without the problem I had previously - thanks and apologies!